# Use ImagField from Django to save image paths in different directory other than MEDIA_ROOT

Tags: django, admin, imagefield

I have created a Model that should only be accessed by the admin user and I would like to user the admin interface to manage theinstances I create. So basically this will be used to generate static.

One of the fields I would like to use is the ImageField that saves references to image in the MEDIA_ROOT. However, I would prefer to have those images references inside the STATIC_ROOT instead of MEDIA_ROOT in order not to have them mixed up with user generated data.

Is it possible to set this without hardcoding?
Thanks in advance

Pedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by defining custom file storage:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

image_store = FileSystemStorage(location='/tmp/images')

class YourModel(models.Model):
      image = models.ImageField(storage=image_store)
```

Comment: Instead of location='/path/to/' can I use directly the STATIC_ROOT+'something/else/' ?